# What is causing "Unable to find suitable address." when trying to mount samba share on Centos 6?

Tags: samba, centos6

I am trying to share a directory on a centos box. I tested out configuring it on my ubuntu desktop before trying it on the centos machine and every thing worked fine. The smb.conf is setup the same and I have done smbpasswd as well as added the user to /etc/samba/smbusers. When I try to mount the share I get the message "Unable to find suitable address".

I thought it might be that because the samba server is Centos 6 it might be an SELinux issue. So after a little google I found this: http://aaronwalrath.wordpress.com/2011/03/26/install-samba-server-on-red-hat-enterprise-linux-6scientific-linux-6/ After doing the things mentioned there I still get the same Unable to find suitable address message.

In /var/log/samba/log.smb I have this output.

```
[2011/08/22 11:07:42.198369,  0] printing/print_cups.c:108(cups_connect)
  Unable to connect to CUPS server localhost:631 - Connection refused
[2011/08/22 11:07:42.202031,  0] printing/print_cups.c:108(cups_connect)
  Unable to connect to CUPS server localhost:631 - Connection refused
[2011/08/22 11:07:43.224267,  0] smbd/server.c:500(smbd_open_one_socket)
  smbd_open_once_socket: open_socket_in: Address already in use
[2011/08/22 11:07:43.224689,  0] smbd/server.c:500(smbd_open_one_socket)
  smbd_open_once_socket: open_socket_in: Address already in use
```

I read that this is a bug and that output does not mean that samba wont work from here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=726936

What could cause this? Is there anything special that needs to be configured in Centos 6 vs Centos 5 for samba? I am pretty sure most of the info I see on line about Centos and samba is from before the time that Centos 6 was released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that Centos 6 had iptables running by default and it was blocking communication on that port. I hope this helps any one else who runs into this sort of thing in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I have had this problem just a second ago. Solution for this problem was adding parameter "bind interfaces only = yes". Example configuration below:

```
interfaces = lo eth0 127.0.0.1 192.168.1.99
hosts allow = 127. 192.168.1.
bind interfaces only = yes # << <<< <<<< <<<<<<
```